# undefined method error draper gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, draper

I am trying to user draper gem and looks like I set up just fine, however, when I call method inside my draper method, I get an "undefined method error" Here is what I have done so far.

```
gem 'draper'

bundle install

rails g decorator MyModel
```

in my Decorator, I have the follow code.

```
class TaskDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all
  decorates :task

  def dummy

    print "Hello World"

  end
end
```

In my controller

```
  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
    @task = TaskDecorator.find_by(:id => params[:id])
  end
```

My View

```
<%= @task.dummy %>
```

Run in the browser, I get the following error

```
undefined method `dummy' for #<Task:0x007fad7a639d48>
```

Any idea, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing your:

`TaskDecorator.find_by(:id => params[:id])`

with:

`Task.find(params[:id]).decorate`

(EDIT: didn't have enough reputation to comment on the original question so original answer was asking if OP had found a solution. Now edited to include the solution I found. Admittedly an old post but leaving this here in case anybody else comes across the same problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also call `decorates_finders` in `TaskDecorator` like this:

```
class TaskDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all
  decorates :task
  decorates_finders

  def dummy

    print "Hello World"

  end
end
```

Then you can get your decorated model by calling

```
Task.find(params[:id])
```